# Trying to recast $*ARGFILES

Tags: io, raku

In order to [fix this error](https://github.com/raku-community-modules/perl6-IO-CatHandle-AutoLines/issues/1) I would need to re-cast $*ARGFILES as a IO::CatHandle, since it uses some attributes of that class. I'm trying this:

```
use IO::CatHandle::AutoLines; # -*- mode:perl6 -*-
use Test;

if $*ARGFILES === $*IN {
    $*ARGFILES = IO::CatHandle.new( $*IN );
}
eval-lives-ok "$*ARGFILES does IO::CatHandle::AutoLines", "Can recast \$*ARGFILES";
```

But this yields the error:

```
# Error: Unsupported use of <STDIN>; in Perl 6 please use $*IN.lines (or add whitespace to suppress warning)
```

This is independent, I think, of the role I'm mixing, but I add it for context. Any idea of what else could be done?

Answer (score 11):

The error you see is very LTA, but a side-effect of using double quotes, when you should have been using single quotes:

```
eval-lives-ok '$*ARGFILES does IO::CatHandle::AutoLines',
  "Can recast \$*ARGFILES";
# ok 1 - Can recast $*ARGFILES
```

So you're trying to stringify `$*ARGFILES`, which yields the string:

```
<STDIN> does IO::CatHandle::AutoLines
```

and that does not `EVAL` very well  :-)

Comment: So I guess the recast is OK?

Comment: Yes, the test was flawed.